# DateFormatter.localizedString is broken for some of the dates

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

This is what I do when picker changes:

```
extension Date {
    var fromCurrentToUTC: Date {
        return addingTimeInterval(-TimeInterval(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()))
    }
}    


var title = "--"

if let date = datePickerView.date?.fromCurrentToUTC {
    title = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: date, dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .none)
}

print("-----")
print(datePickerView.date!)
print(title)
print(TimeZone.current)
print(datePickerView.date!.timeIntervalSince1970)

dateTimeSegmentControl.setTitle(title, forSegmentAt: 0)
```

And this is how it looks for the dates:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Assuming. Everything is fine for the dates before 6th November, and everything is off after 6th November. Why?

**update:**

That critical date is different for every time zone I use. For example:

Warsaw (+0200) the date is 30 October
Chicago (-0500) the date is 6th November

The ordered prints:

```
-----
2017-11-04 00:00:00 +0000
4 Nov 2017
America/New_York (current)
1509753600.0
-----
2017-11-05 00:00:00 +0000
5 Nov 2017
America/New_York (current)
1509840000.0
-----
2017-11-06 00:00:00 +0000
5 Nov 2017
America/New_York (current)
1509926400.0
-----
2017-11-07 00:00:00 +0000
6 Nov 2017
America/New_York (current)
1510012800.0
```

Comment: Most probably due to  the end of daylight saving time (which is on Nov 5 2017 in Warsaw and on October 29 2017 in Chicago).

Comment: what?;) how can I do workaround for this?

Comment: It seems to work fine for Finland (29th October) - do not see any wrong dates with DateFormatter.localizedString

Comment: The DateFormatter code looks correct at first sight, so `date` must be wrong. Show the output of `print(date, title)` and `print(TimeZone.current)` for a problematic date.

Comment: ... and  `print(date.timeIntervalSince1970)`

Comment: @MartinR I will add prints within a few minutes...

Comment: @MartinR I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function

```
extension Date {
    var fromCurrentToUTC: Date {
        return addingTimeInterval(-TimeInterval(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()))
    }
}
```

the GMT offset of the *current date* is subtracted, not
by the GMT offset of the date to be adjusted. Therefore you get
a wrong result if the date to be adjusted is in a DST period and the current date is not, or vice versa.

That can be fixed by using

```
extension Date {
    var fromCurrentToUTC: Date {
        return addingTimeInterval(-TimeInterval(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT(for: self)))
    }
}
```

instead. However, a better solution would be to set the timezone
of the date formatter to UTC, instead of adjusting the date:

```
if let date = datePickerView.date {
    let fmt = DateFormatter()
    fmt.dateStyle = .medium
    fmt.timeStyle = .none
    fmt.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    let title = fmt.string(from: date)
    print(title)
}
```

Comment: Should it work then? Now I have problems with new xcode, but check it soon

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: It worked in my test, but you should verify it yourself.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: Note that a better solution would be to use a custom date formatter with the timezone set to UTC, instead of adjusting the date.

Comment: but custom date formatter will prevent me from using a local format date... once it is `July 27, 2017` or `27 July 2017`

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: I have added an example.