# Add current timezone difference to timeintervalsince1970 in swift

Tags: swift, date

I have an API call that asks me to convert dates to `timeIntervalSince1970` in ms and they also want me to add the correct time zone difference. So my code is at the moment:

```
if let timeStamp = incident?.publishedTimeStamp as Date? {
   let roundedDown = Int(timeStamp.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    publishedDate = String(roundedDown)
}
```

This gives me a number that if I insert it in here:
https://www.epochconverter.com/

I get this result:
[image: example]

Now as you can see, the `GMT` time (the top result) is what I at the moment achieve. I need to add enough ms so that the **Your time zone** section would be in the `GMT` section. I hope this makes sense.

So how can I get the number in ms that represents the difference between the current time zone from `GMT` so I can sum it with my current result?

Comment: As stated in the documents, date is `a specific point in time, independent of any calendar or time zone`. Do your necessary setup on the date formatter when you use the date object.

Comment: @Desdenova well, I have the ms from the date. I want to get the difference in ms to add to that date. I am not formatting the date or changing it. Just trying to do the math for converting the ms so it fits my API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var roundedDown = Double(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT(for: timeStamp)) + timeStamp.timeIntervalSince1970
roundedDown *= 1000
publishedDate = String(Int(roundedDown))
```

Comment: @Eyzuky:  This will give wrong results if the current date is in DST and the timestamp is not, or vice versa. You should use `secondsFromGMT(for: timeStamp)` instead. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/46321970/1187415 for a similar issue.